# Lucene hibernate search NumericRangeQuery<Float> not working on field defined with @NumericField

Tags: lucene, numeric, hibernate-search, range

I use hibernate search 4.1.0 with good results except for this problem.
I´m trying to perform a range search in a column defined:

```
@Field(name = "startTime", store = Store.YES)
@NumericField
public Float startTime;
```

I have stored an item with startTime = 0.0f;

then I try to perform a range query:

```
NumericRangeQuery<Float> rangeQuery = NumericRangeQuery.newFloatRange(
                "startDate", -100000.0f, +100000.0f, true, true);
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager
                .createFullTextQuery(rangeQuery, Item.class);
results = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

**First**: I have no results.

**Second**: Inspecting the index with lukeall, I see simply stored what seems to be the toString() [judging by other experiments too], which looks not normal...

I feel like I´m missing something, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replied on the [Hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2456729#p2456729) first, reposting here for the sake of other readers:

**first**: I think you're targeting the wrong field name; the field name is `startTime`, not `startDate`. In this case since you are wrapping a Lucene Query directly we can't check for it's validity.

**second**: what you see in Luke is the result of `Store.YES`